# firebase.database.Reference.set returns promise which resolves even in offline mode

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I working on a frontend app which based on firebase (v4.6.2) and I have a function like this:

```
function saveSomeData(data) {
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/some/reference")
    .set(data)
    .then(
      () => {
        // Success callback is always executed (even in offline mode).
      },
      reason => {
        // Error callback is never executed for some reason :-(
      }
    );
}
```

I decided to test app behavior in case of some error (for example in case of disconnect). I expected, that returned promise will be rejected, but it isn't. Firebase documentation says, that this promise will be resolved after synchronization with remote server completed (which sounds reasonable), but looks like it behaves in a different way...

So, the question is: how to force it to reject the promise in case of offline (I don't need all the fancy offline capabilities for sure)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is re-establishes a connection when a connection is dropped.

All requests made when a connection is dropped are kept in a queue and *sync-ed* when a connection is re-established.

Errors leading to a promise rejection include validation errors with keys, errors trying to write to a protected reference such as `.info/*` amongst many others but not connection errors.

In any case, syncing of update & set operations can be stopped when there is a disconnection by [cancelling queued requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect#cancel) for the reference.

Such query will look like so.

```
function saveSomeData(data) {
  const ref = firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/some/reference");

  return ref.set(data)
    .then(
      () => {
          ref.onDisconnect().cancel(); 
        // Success callback is always executed (even in offline mode).
      },
      reason => {
        // Error callback is never executed for some reason :-(
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a good answer, I suspected that it have much more under the hood.